# How to evaluate performance on small data sets

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Let's say that I have three queries returning the same result in MSSQL and my database is too small to measure the execution time accurately, or I do not trust my server's resources enough to get promising results. Still, I would like to know which query will be the fastest if I run it using tables with millions of rows. For example, in SSMS Express 2014, an exact query execution plan for the batch below will say, that they all have the same cost relative to the batch, equal 33%. You can run the following on the TSQL2012 sample database.

```
    select e.empid from 
hr.Employees e left join 
sales.orders o on e.empid = o.empid and orderdate = '20080212'
    where o.empid is null

    select e.empid from 
hr.Employees e
    where not exists (SELECT * from sales.orders o where o.empid = e.empid and  orderdate = '20080212')

    select empid from hr.Employees
    except
    select empid from sales.orders where orderdate = '20080212'
```

Now, I do not believe that all these queries have EXACTLY the same cost. Is there any way in which I can evaluate those more precisely, without  running this batch on a bigger database? Using SSMS would be preferred, although I am curious of external tools as well.

Comment: Populate your test tables with millions of rows.

Comment: Yep, that is what I was trying to avoid. Well, maybe not avoid, but I am curious if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: This is the **better** way actually. And the more complex and more realistic data you will provide - the more significant results of testing you will gain.